# PERL: Input datetime, create a start and end point from parts of input and check if inbetween

Tags: perl

As a beginner I struggle abit.

I want to get a datetime input from the user like this.

> 2018/06/21-10:30

Then I have two other times that marks the start and end for a daily period of time.

> 09:00 and 14:00

What I want is for the script to take the input. Apply the date part to the two other times so they will be like this:

> 2018/06/21-09:00 and 2018/06/21-14:00

Then I want to run the input from the user and check if the time entered is within the time of the two other newly formed datetimes.

Are there any great way to do this? Or another approach to this?

::EDIT 1::

Okey. I have been playing around abit and I have found a way.
Any suggestions or am I going the right path?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use utf8;
use open qw(:encoding(UTF-8) :std);

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

print " Enter START with following pattern Y/m/d-H:M -> ";
chomp ( my $input1 = <> );

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M');

my $dt1 = $parser->parse_datetime($input1) or die;

my $wd_start_ftd = $dt1->ymd('/')."-09:00";
my $wd_stop_ftd = $dt1->ymd('/')."-14:00";

print "\n Start of the day is ", $wd_start_ftd;
print "\n End of the day is ", $wd_stop_ftd;
```

That gives me this

> Enter START with following pattern Y/m/d-H:M -> 2018/06/07-10:30
>
> Start of the day is 2018/06/07-09:00  End of the day is
>   2018/06/07-14:00

Now all i need is to get something up to test if the input is ib between start and stop values.

Comment: because you have a formatted dare/time that goes from YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm ( all components from ‘big’ to ‘small’ units, for simple things like this, one can so simple string comparisons. Sometimes things are not so complicated at all

Comment: and checking if something is ‘in between’ is a check that is usually done in two steps. Since you want to check something like $a < $x < $b that is basically the same as: ($a < $x) and ($x < $b). Success, happy coding, TIMTOWTDI

Comment: The module you found, [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.49/lib/DateTime.pm), is the most rounded one for dates and times. It comes with a lot of functionality; browse its documentation.  Comparison of dates is done with its class method [compare](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.49/lib/DateTime.pm#DateTime-%3Ecompare%28_$dt1,_$dt2_%29,_DateTime-%3Ecompare_ignore_floating%28_$dt1,_$dt2_%29), as `DateTime->compare($dt1, $dt2)` where you get `1`/`-1`/`0`. See docs.

Comment: ... or just trust the magic of overloading and that one can simply compare two DateTime objects. If you can make a clone, like: `$dt_start = $dt1->clone` and then change the time: `$dt_start->set_hour(09); $dt_start->set_minute(00)`, same for `$dt_end` At this moment, you can now safely compare the three DateTime objects: `$dt_start lt $dt1 and $dt1 lt $dt_end` --- See [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a fully working example. It may require some adjustments for your own personal preferences, like what you want to have for input message and the printing of other things. But you probably know how to do that!

If you run the script, it will wait for input in the `YYYY/MM/DD-hh:mm` format and will let you know if it is between 9am and 2pm,.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

chomp ( my $input =  <>  );

my $strptime = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M');

my $dt_check = $strptime->parse_datetime($input);
my $dt_start = clone_with_time($dt_check, '09:00');
my $dt_stops = clone_with_time($dt_check, '14:00');


my $check = ( $dt_start lt $dt_check and $dt_check lt $dt_stops ) ? "Yay": "Nay";

print "$check\n";

# return a cloned DateTime object, set with the given time
sub clone_with_time {
    my ($dt_old, $time) = @_;
    my ($hh, $mm) = split /:/, $time;
    my $dt_new = $dt_old->clone;
    $dt_new->set( hour => $hh, minute => $mm);
    return $dt_new
}
```

The `clone_with_time` subroutine takes a DateDime object (the one we got from the input) and a time string in the `hh:mm` format. The subroutine then clones that object and sets the time accordingly.

Subroutines are nice to have if one needs to repeat some statements multiple times, in this example, to generate `$dt_start` and `$dt_stops`. It keeps the main program clean and easy to follow. while coding, keep [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in mind.

TIMTOWTDI

Comment:  wondering why a 'vote down'  while it provides all the details to solve the problem ❓